# How implement automatic text reply using node.js and firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to setup a service where anyone call text "help" to 321 and recieve some response. How can this be accomplished using javascript/node.js and firebase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it just with Firebase/Nodejs. You will need to use a 3rd party service to integrate with the cell/phone networks. I've used Twilio in the past and it's been pretty straight forward. Check out [these docs for their Node.JS intro](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node).

Edit:
Just a warning - You'll have to be on a paid Firebase plan to interact with a non-Google service (*such as Twilio*)